# How to multicite volumes style-independently

Tags: biblatex, citing

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)

The family of multicite commands based on `\cites` typeset two or more citations from a list of keys. For example, `\parencites[<page>]{<key>}[<page>]{<key>}`.

However, I can't find anything like `\volcites` or even `\avolcites`.

My question is: How can I cite two or more volumes of a multivolume work in a single multicite command? Also, is it possible to do it style-independently?

In short, I'm looking for this: `\avolcites{<vol>}[<page>]{<key>}{<vol>}[<page>]{<key>}`.

Comment: Wouldn't the 'many' volumes need their own, independent bibkeys and therefore be `\cite`-able through the normal mechanisms you mention?

Comment: Not necessarily. A single bibkey `key` may refer to a multivolume work that can be cited by volume-and-page; for example, `\volcite{<vol>}[<page>]{<key>}`. But I'm looking for a way to *multicite* a multivolume work; for example, for a single three-volumes `key`, I could be something like `\volcites{1}[100]{<key>}{2}[200]{key}{3}[300]{<key>}`, and preferably style-independently, such as `\avolcites`. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolaiRostov What output are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: For example, a footnote like this: "¹John. _Complete Works_, volume 2, page 200; Mary. _Selected Works_, volume 3, page 300." Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest biblatex version. Multicite variants of `\volcite` and friends were introduced in biblatex 2.7. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
\cmd{volcite}: \volcite[See]{A}[10]{knuth:ct} \\
\cmd{volcites}: \volcites(See)(){A}[10]{knuth:ct}{B}[10--15]{knuth:ct}{C}{knuth:ct} \\
\cmd{tvolcite}: \tvolcite[See]{A}[10]{knuth:ct}. \\
\cmd{tvolcites}: \tvolcites(See)(){A}[10]{knuth:ct}{B}[10--15]{knuth:ct}{C}{knuth:ct}. \\
\cmd{avolcite}: Filler \avolcite[See]{A}[10]{knuth:ct}. \\
\cmd{avolcites}: Filler \avolcites(See)(){A}[10]{knuth:ct}{B}[10--15]{knuth:ct}{C}{knuth:ct}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @NicolaiRostov No problem. Thanks for the question. It should probably be addressed with a new biblatex feature at some point.

Comment: It would be great if it were implemented. Why don't you submit it? It works pretty well!

Comment: @NicolaiRostov I'm not entirely happy with the format handling. This will be on my style todo list.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the repeated printing of the reference to the multivolume work? In the above example, what I'm looking for its for foonote 4 to read: "See Knuth, *Computers & Typesetting*, vol. A, p. 10; vol. B, pp. 10–15; vol. C."